# .shx files disappeared/deleted?

Tags: shapefile

I am quite new with QGIS and I created some maps with different layers these last weeks (seems easy but took me hours to do so). As usual, I saved everything in a folder yesterday, but today, I couldn't open my project or the shapefiles. It says "datasource is not recognized..." and, as I checked, I realized the .shx files are all missing. 
I read in one of the discussions here on Stack Exchange that it may be caused by an antivirus "cleaning" some folders (I have Avira).

Is it possible that Avira has deleted these files?

How can I get them back and avoid that this happens again next time?

Comment: Update: I was able to recreate the shapefiles using ShapeViewer... However, I still doesn't know why the shx files disappeared and how to avoid it in the future...

Comment: Anti-virus software deleting files sounds like it may belong on another SE site like [**Super User**](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: This is a good site to post your question on, Lily, because we tend to have a lot of experience with shapefiles.  I would like to suggest that if your question sits here for a few days with no good answer, then you flag it for moderator attention and request that it be *migrated* to SU.  That will keep all the comments and partial answers (if any) together in one place for your convenience (and that of all future readers).  Thank you!